# ImportError: cannot import name PolyDrawTool (Not able to Import - PolyDrawTool)

Tags: python, python-2.7, bokeh, importerror

[I am Trying to run this example](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/examples/tools_poly_draw.html) (Not able to Import - PolyDrawTool)

- https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/examples/tools_poly_draw.html

Python **2.7** 
bokeh **v0.12**

Got Import Error :

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-cc6a3ae44bb8> in <module>()
      1 from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
----> 2 from bokeh.models import PolyDrawTool
      3 
      4 output_file("tools_poly_draw.html")
      5 

ImportError: cannot import name PolyDrawTool
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PolyDrawTool` is a very recent feature, it is much newer then version `0.12`. You will need to update your Bokeh version to be able to use it. The latest current release is `0.12.15`.